# Internal Error After Installing react-native-country-picker-modal

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Hello when I install react-native-country-picker-modal and add this `import CountryPicker, {getAllCountries} from 'react-native-country-picker-modal';` to my component i receive this error in the sim. When I remove this line the error is gone.

```
{"type":"internalError","message":"react-packager has encountered an internal error, pelase check your terminal error output for more details"}
```

**I tried to fix it for hours and can't solve the issue. Any ideas why this is happening or how to fix it?**

Here is what happens when i install this package.

```
$ npm i react-native-country-picker-modal --save
taddar_mobile_app@0.0.1 /Users/josephkonop/Documents/Projects/taddar_mobile_app
└─┬ react-native-country-picker-modal@0.3.0-rc1
  └── react-native-emoji@1.2.0  (git://github.com/niftylettuce/react-native-emoji.git#70275d5e36cc9933f4d571fae7fa519ab566ca38)

npm WARN react-static-container@1.0.1 requires a peer of react@^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 but none was installed.
```

Logs

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:725:19)
    at Object.readSync (/Users/my_name/Documents/Projects/taddar_mobile_app/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:138:28)
    at tryReadSync (fs.js:480:20)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:528:19)
    at _readSourceCodePromise.resolve (/Users/my_name/Documents/Projects/taddar_mobile_app/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/Module.js:191:31)
    at Module._readSourceCode (/Users/my_name/Documents/Projects/taddar_mobile_app/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/Module.js:190:37)
    at Module._readDocBlock (/Users/my_name/Documents/Projects/taddar_mobile_app/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/Module.js:199:29)
    at Module._getHasteName (/Users/my_name/Documents/Projects/taddar_mobile_app/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/Module.js:209:32)
    at _cache.get (/Users/my_name/Documents/Projects/taddar_mobile_app/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/Module.js:130:18)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kill your local packaging server and restart it. I had this same issue and the solution was to restart the packaging server. I also installed this via NPM, not sure if that helps.